# HTML Table Tag without the Thead Tag

Tags: html

Is the markup still valid if I try to use a table tag without the thead tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the HTML Living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element), it is optional inside a `<TABLE>` tag. The '?' in `THEAD?` means optional.

Answer (score 3):

[validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

yes, thread is not needed.